# Modify VALUE inside LIST located in JSON DICTIONARY

Tags: python, json, urllib

I would like to ask this is my JSON file. if I would like to change my 'c' to '9', how do I write for the data?

```
{
   'x': 4,
   'y': 5,
   'z': [
     {
       'a': 1, 
       'b': 2, 
       'c': 3
     }
   ]
}
```

```
import urllib.request
import json

data = ?????
myurl = "http://192.168.1.10:8888/testJSON"

req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(data)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   # needs to be bytes
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

The Solution provided by @BhagyeshDudhediya is working:

```
import urllib.request
import json

data['z'][0]['c'] = 9
myurl = "http://192.168.1.10:8888/testJSON"

req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(data)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   # needs to be bytes
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

Comment: do you wan to change `'c': 3` to `'c': 9`?

Comment: Is this what you want: `data['z'][0]['c'] = 9`?

Comment: @Sabil yes, I want to change 'c' from 3 to 9

Comment: @BhagyeshDudhediya Correct, based on what I know, if I wanna change x from 4 to 6 I just need to put data = { x : 6 }. For data['z'][0]['c'] I not sure how to do it.

Comment: `data['z'][0]['c'] = 9` is the way to go..btw if you just want to change x from 4 to 6 it should be done as `data['x']=6`, if you do `data={x:6}`, your entire dictionary will be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this: `data['z'][0]['c'] = 9`